# C# Deserializing nested xml

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I have the following code to deseriaze an xml string in C#.

Everything works fine and I am able to deserialize it to an object. However, the ProjectNode value is always empty.

Can someone please help me make this code work or point out what am I missing?

The sample XML has been included in the code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace DeserializeSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static string XML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><response clientos=\"Windows\" datetimepattern=\"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a\"><info><![CDATA[<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><transaction loglevel=\"0\" type=\"response\"><arguments><argument name=\"id\">1</argument><argument name=\"foredit\">True</argument><argument name=\"ScheduleOn\">Estimated</argument><argument name=\"xml\"><Project xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/project\"><UID>0</UID><ID>0</ID></Project></argument></arguments></transaction>]]></info></response>";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ProjectResponse projectResponse = CreateFromXml(XML, typeof(ProjectResponse)) as ProjectResponse;
        }

        public static object CreateFromXml(string data, Type msfRequestResponseType)
        {
            object projectResponse = null;
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(msfRequestResponseType, "");
                XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings() { ProhibitDtd = true };

                // We have content in the part so create xml reader and load the xml into XElement.
                using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(data), settings))
                {
                    projectResponse = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return projectResponse;
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot("response")]
    [Serializable]
    public class ProjectResponse
    {
        [XmlAnyAttribute()]
        public XmlAttribute[] ResponseAttributes { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("info")]
        public ProjectResponseInfoTag InfoTag { get; set; }

        public class ProjectResponseInfoTag
        {
            private string infoText = string.Empty;

            [XmlText]
            public string InfoText
            {
                get { return infoText; }
                set
                {
                    infoText = value;
                    Transaction = Program.CreateFromXml(infoText, typeof(ProjectTransaction)) as ProjectTransaction;
                }
            }

            [XmlElement("transaction")]
            public ProjectTransaction Transaction { get; set; }

            [XmlRoot("transaction")]
            public class ProjectTransaction
            {
                [XmlAnyAttribute]
                public XmlAttribute[] TransactionAttributes { get; set; }

                [XmlElement("arguments")]
                public ProjectArguments Arguments { get; set; }

                public class ProjectArguments
                {
                    [XmlElement("argument")]
                    public List<ProjectArgument> ArgList { get; set; }

                    public class ProjectArgument
                    {
                        [XmlAttribute("name")]
                        public string Name { get; set; }

                        [XmlText]
                        public string ArgValue { get; set; }

                        [XmlElement("Project")]
                        public Project ProjectNode { get; set; }

                        public class Project
                        {
                            [XmlAnyElement()]
                            public XmlElement[] ProjectElements { get; set; }

                            [XmlAnyAttribute()]
                            public XmlAttribute[] ProjectAttributes { get; set; }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xml namespaces; try

```
[XmlElement("Project", Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/project")]
```